# Social media login fb login and other need tutorial for magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used an extension and integrated fb login with the Facebook App ID & Facebook App Secret key but in the end getting some error as "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."
Could anyone please suggest a better tutorial and any free extension for magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Its done with the following steps...

At

> app/code/community/namespace/module/controllers/FacebookController.php

```
<!-- Replace this -->
$userInfo = $client->api('/me');

<1-- with this code --> 
$userInfo = $client->api('/me','GET', array(
                'fields' => 'id,name,first_name,last_name,link,birthday,gender,email,picture.type(large)'
                ));
```

and then in mail I received the newly generated password with which am able to login.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of free extension available for facebook login in magento 1.9

please check this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/), it's a best example for facebook login and make sure all the steps followed what they mentioned in tutorial.

Comment: I have managed to register through fb account but after that when I go to  login page and login with the fb credentials from which i have registered it says invalid credentials. Any solution ?

Comment: did you verify your facebook account

Comment: How do i  verify facebook account ?